# rcs -u motd breaking a lock

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, rcs

I am trying to use the rcs command to break a lock on a file but whenever I input on ubuntu:

```
rcs -u motd
```

it says:

> rcs: RCS/motd,v: no such file or directory.

The file is there because I can use the cat command and edit it using vi.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try rlog motd, which should give you information from the file RCS/motd,v  . If that also gives you "no such file or directory", then it's the file motd,v in the subdirectory RCS, which doesn't exist or you can't access.